# Android IllegalStateException: Fragment already active when calling notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to Android, and looks like there are still some things missing in my understanding of the activity lifecycle. I have a tabbed application created with a `FragmentActivity`. A custom `ViewPager` is managing the presentation of tabs and in one of those tabs I want a simple drill-down with the ability to use the hardware "Back" button to go back up a level to the previous view.

I implemented this drill-down by just substituting an appropriate `Fragment` into the tab by checking the value of a flag (which determines where in the drill down we are):

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
   Fragment fragment; 

   switch (position) {
   case 0 : 
     if (stateFlag == 0) fragment = (Fragment) new InitialFragment();
     else fragment = (Fragment) new FinalResultsFragment();
     break;
   case 1: 
     fragment = (Fragment) new SecondTabFragment();
     break;
    default:
     fragment = (Fragment) new ThirdTabFragment();
     break;
  }

  return fragment;
}
```

To go back to the "previous" Fragment I do this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int p = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

    switch (p) {
    case 0:
        if (stateFlag == 0)) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            stateFlag = 0;
            mViewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        }
        break;
    default:
        super.onBackPressed();
        break;
    }
 }
```

This works fine, until I try changing the orientation. The `Fragment`s come back from that change successfully, but when I try pressing the Back button while in the `FinalResultsFragment` state, I get

```
IllegalStateException: Fragment already active
E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(PagerAdapter.java:276)
```

Why is the change in orientation breaking this particular part of the code?

Edit:

So if I open the app, first tab active, I press a button that loads a different fragment in that tab, then press the Back button - it's all good and the first fragment is loaded, as expected.

But if I open the app, first tab active, I press a button that loads a different fragment in that tab, the rotate the screen, the fragment is re-loaded just fine, then press the Back button - crash!

Edit:

here is the complete error log: http://pastebin.com/ESDTstsm

Comment: Remember than when you change orientation the fragment is destroyed and re-created

Comment: Your problem sounds related to Fragment life cycle management on orientation change. Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10463715/1714714).

Comment: But after it is re-created successfully, why is it causing the *adapter* to crash?

Comment: That isn't the entire stacktrace isn't it?